# Http connection limit on webworker or service worker

Tags: google-chrome, https, xmlhttprequest, web-worker, service-worker

I know there is a limit of 10 on max connection and 6 per domain for making network request. Is this limit include any network call made from webworker (shared or dedicated) or service worker?

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps you could run some tests and post the results (on a blog, Medium, etc)? I'm sure others would be interested.

Comment: @Kunal wondering if this was ever resolved?